# Convenient display for console logs from Next js server components in vscode

Tags: next.js, vscode-extensions, console.log, react-server-components

In Nextjs some time i need to `console.log() / .dir` from a server components
so the logs appears in the terminal.
Now, in the Chrome console, I can toggle and explore object properties, which helps when dealing with nested objects. However, VScode terminal doesn't provide the same visual experience.

Is there a solution or recommended extension that allows for interactive object viewing in Visual Studio Code? I want to be able to expand object properties and navigate through nested objects easily within the Visual Studio Code terminal. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

in short, I want to be able to expand objects and navigate through nested objects when i console.log a js object from the server side.